# XMLHttpRequest handling with Flask: best way to do it

Tags: javascript, python, flask, xmlhttprequest

I wrote a simple web server that get a photo and store it in the server.
I am not expert about javascript and I looking for some tips that help me to found a good way to manage data between js and Flask.

This is my index.html file where I create a small form in where insert the photo and a button that run a small js function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Take or select photo(s) and upload</title>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function fileSelected() {
        var count = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;
              document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = "";
              for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++)
              {
                     var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];
                     var fileSize = 0;
                     if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
                            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
                     else
                            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
                     document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += 'Name: ' + file.name + '<br>Size: ' + fileSize + '<br>Type: ' + file.type;
                     document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += '<p>';
              }
      }

      function uploadFile() {
        var fd = new FormData();
              var count = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;
              for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++)
              {
                     var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];
                     //console.log(file)
                     fd.append(file.name, file);
                     
              }
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "/save", true);
        xhr.send(fd);
        console.log(fd)
      }

      function uploadProgress(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
          var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
          document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
        }
      }
      function uploadComplete(evt) {
        /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
        alert(evt.target.responseText);
      }

      function uploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
      }

      function uploadCanceled(evt) {
        alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
    <div>
      <label for="fileToUpload">Take or select photo(s)</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
    </div>
    <div id="details"></div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()"  value="Upload" />
    </div>
    <div id="progress"></div>

  </form>

  <br><br>
  <h3>{{message}}</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request,redirect, flash
import base64
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5
import json


#instatiate flask app
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./templates')
bootstrap = Bootstrap5(app)


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print(request.method)
    status = ""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('./index.html', message=status)
    else:
        try:
            #photo = request.files['fileToUpload']
            for key  in request.files.keys:
                print(request.files.get(key))
            #photo.save("upload/myfile.jpg")
            #status='Uploaded'
            #flash("Updated")
        except:
            status = "Something went wrong"

        return render_template("./index.html", message=status)

@app.route('/save', methods = ['POST'])
def save():
    try:
        
        files = request.files.lists()
        for photo in files:
            photo[1][0].save("upload/{0}".format(photo[0]))  
        return redirect("/")
    except:
        return render_template("./index.html", message="FAILED")
    
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

My question is: there are a better way to do this? Maybe using json or converting files to a dict instead of list?
Can it support multiple users at the same time?
Can I handling the request with an async function on flask side?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Your Flask app can be simplified quite a lot:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

# instatiate flask app
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./templates')
bootstrap = Bootstrap5(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/save', methods=['POST'])
def save():
    files = request.files.values()
    for photo in files:
        filename = secure_filename(photo.filename)
        photo.save(os.path.join('upload', filename))
    return 'Upload successful'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Since you only POST to `/save`, you don't need any logic for POST in `index`. I've changed the `save` route to use `secure_filename` for safety. You don't need a try/except in `save` because if it fails, your `uploadFailed` JavaScript will be called.

Your JavaScript looks good, but you need to add the `multiple` attribute to the file input to accept multiple files:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="image/*" capture="camera" multiple/>
```

If you want to support multiple users, have a look at [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/) or this [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! This is simpler than my code. I don't care handling multi-user login but can happen that more than one user upload a photo at the same time, do i need to implement the login?

Comment: Moreover my initial idea was to manage GET and PUT inside my index page, this is why index function has a little logic part behind

Comment: It should handle multiple users uploading at the same time if you set up your web server correctly. You don't need login, I misunderstood what you meant.